# Undo-Last-Action in php: Storing hashed queries in MySQL?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, security, user-experience

Good day. I am about to go ahead and implement an undo-last-action system on my website. Addressing those experts out there, would you say that I should not do it my method for whatever reason? I'll explain the procedure below.

Client side, the user can use their keyboard to press Ctrl + Z to undo the last action. I use jQuery for this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 'z') {
    var UndoLastAction = confirm('Undo last action?');
    if (UndoLastAction === false) {
      return; //don't do anything.
    } else {
      //use ajax to fetch the latest row in the DB in table called "undo_actions"
      //unhash the query, then execute it. Client never sees the code.
    }
  }
});
```

I created a table in my database that is structured as such:

```
CREATE TABLE undo_actions (
id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
undo_code TEXT not null, /*Hashed sql query to undo the last action. Once this code is used up (i.e. when ctrl Z is confirmed) then delete this row so as to avoid double-undoing and other errors. Since this will be sql code, stringyfy it well, and stripslashes when executing it. An example of this code would be: "UPDATE users SET username = my_old_username WHERE user_id = 1" and hashed before it's been inserted into the DB */
date_of_action DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

The above table will be populated each time I do anything (that I would like to later edit/delete) on my website, such as, change my username, change my password, change my customer order number, and so on. Whenever I make such a change, I also log a "reverse" query into the `undo_code` column, saving the old values into that query, hashing the query, and inserting it into the database.

The reason I came up with this system is for the sake of simplicity. If you think this is a major security hazard which I should stay away from, kindly share your input :-)

Comment: So you are planning to have the client-side directly send SQL to the server, and then run it there? Don't...

Comment: The client is doing nothing more than editing his own data. I use the exact same code when signing a user up.

Comment: your comment in the `else` part of the JS code has this: `unhash the query, then execute it.`... it's a little confusing

Comment: so after you run the reverse query on the server-side, how do you reflect the changes in the client-side?

Comment: The changes will be seen by the client immediately. If their original username was "john doe" and they decided to change it to "doe john", they can press Ctrl + Z and their username will go back to "john doe".

Comment: but how will this be implemented?

Comment: What do you mean, how will it be implemented? I've written all of the details in the question that I can think of.

Comment: i understand that on the server-side there will be a pre-prepared reverse query that would change "doe john" back to "john doe". but i don't understand what mechanism will tell the client-side to update the user's name. how will the client-side know if the ctrl+z should cause a refresh of the user name, or a deletion of the product last added to the cart?

Comment: I'm building an "Undo Last Action" system, which means that the very last action a client performed may be undone. Any "form field" that a user can submit, can be undone. However that is unrelated to my question. The main question is about whether this is a security hazard.

Comment: but there's a UI, right? updating the DB Is not enough. or you plan to refresh the entire page after each undo?

Comment: It is regrettable we don't know what your website does. Sometimes being able to go back just one step is sufficient, but often it isn't. That depends on what your website does. Can multiple users interact with the same data? That might completely ruin this system.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware all the examples say "change my ..." so presumably the data is not shared between users. though there might still be multiple open tabs (which is another layer of complexity).

Comment: I will be using AJAX and php to send the queries. Also, multiple tabs would not pose a problem, because the row would be deleted once it has been used up. @KIKOSoftware Only one user can interact with their data. If I do plan to allow multiple users to access the same data, I would add an SQL column in the table to restrict that action to allow only the current user to undo his own action. It shouldn't be difficult to do this if there's a log system in place, right?